# Show portion of adjacent fragments in view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is there some way to show a small portion of the adjacent fragments while using the `ViewPager` in Android compatibility package.

The view that I want to make will show the current fragment in center and the edges of the fragments which are before and after the current one on either side.

Comment: Did you have any success making such a component?

Comment: No scompt, I left the problem as is. No direct solution apart from creating a custom component

Answer (score 0):

I believe a ViewPager indicator would be the best solution available. Showing that there are pages to either side.

http://androidforums.com/application-announcements/391561-android-viewpager-indicator.html

Comment: But the requirment that has been put before us want us to show the small edge of the adjacent pages

Comment: Than I think you'll need to find an alternative or write your own component; there is currently no functionality for showing the other pages.